# Почему пункты меню записываются в 2 строки вместо одной?

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть блок с меню. Почему при наведении на первый пункт в выпадающем списке строки со значением "Menu 1", "Menu 2", "Menu 3" переносятся на 2 строки? Это как-то с `flex` связано? Как это можно исправить?

```css
.top-nav_menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.top-nav_menu li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.top-nav_menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.top-nav_menu li.has-child {
  position: relative;
}

.top-nav_menu li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.child-menu {
  display: none;
  background-color: #212121;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: -10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s linear opacity;
  z-index: 9;
}

.child-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 100px 20px 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

.column-left .top-nav_menu .child-menu li>a {
  color: #ffc300;
}

li.has-child:hover .child-menu {
  display: block;
}

.column-left .top-nav_menu li a {
  color: #000;
}

.column-right .top-nav_menu li a {
  color: #ffc300;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <ul class="top-nav_menu">
    <li class="has-child"><a href="#">MENU <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="child-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте к ссылкам white-space: nowrap